# How to convert class to byte array, as per the byte order of C and C++?

Tags: java, c

I am creating a class object to byte array see [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/Convertobjecttobytearrayandconvertbytearraytoobject.htm), and passing this array to `DatagramPacket` to send at destination by means of UDP communication. At the destination side there is C application running and I am getting wired character. I damn sure this related to byte order. Because I am able to convert struct of C into class while receiving packet, but not able to do vice versa. Following is the sudo - code:

```
// recieving part

DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
socket.receive(packet)
UdpPacket udp = new UdpPacket(buffer);

class UdpPacket implements Serializable
{
 int a;
 byte []message = new byte[10];

 public UdpPacket(byte[] data)
 {
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);
    bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    a = bb.getInt();
    bb.get(message);
 }

}

// sending ..
```

Converting UdpPacket object to byte array as per above mentioned link, but at the destination there is always junk values

```
DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();

byte [] respoBytes = ObjectSerializer.serializeObject(udpPacket);

ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(respoBytes);


byte []test = new byte[1116];
bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()); // tried all the orders here
bb.get(test);
DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(test,test.length,client, Integer.parseInt(TxtFdPort.getText().toString()));
clientSocket.send(sendPacket)
```

;

Comment: There I o such thing as 'the byte order of C and C++', but its host hardware does have an endian-ness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Print out the sequence of bytes before sending, and after receiving. This will tell you if they are identical. Then inspect the bytes corresponding to e.g. an `int`, and you will immediately see if they are in the correct order or not.

It's hard to be more specific, since you're not showing the sending code.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious problem is that ignore the length of data read.

```
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
socket.receive(packet);

ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(packet.getData(), 0, packet.getLength());
// you need to know the endianess, not hope it's the same.
bb.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
int a = bb.getInt(); // asuming there is at least 4 bytes.
byte[] message = new byte[bb.remaining()];
bb.get(message);
```

For Sending I would just do this.

```
int port = Integer.parseInt(TxtFdPort.getText().toString());
byte [] respoBytes = ObjectSerializer.serializeObject(udpPacket);
DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(respoBytes, respoBytes.length, client, port);
clientSocket.send(sendPacket);
```

Comment: I am successfully able to receive the data, problem is while sending to destination..

Comment: In that case, I would have thought your sending code is what we need to look at.

Comment: @Yuvi Your ByteBuffer doesn't do anything useful as far as I can see, although it could truncate the message.

Comment: I have already tried as per your suggestion already... the output of int value is something like this `83946924` it should be `5` ..